# LazyHolder uses a static class, why is it called LazyHolder?

Tags: java, singleton

The following code is the LazyHolder method among singleton creation methods.

The inner class has a static directive, but I don't know why it's LazyHolder.

Questions

1. When are classes loaded in Java?
   In my opinion, 1) When an instance is created with a constructor 2) When a static method is called, 3) When a static variables are called
2. When are variables of inner class initialized?
   In Java, when the outer class is loaded, only the member variables are initialized, and the variables of inner class is not initialized?

```java
class SingleTon {
    private SingleTon () {}

    private Static class LazyHolder {
        private Static INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    private static getInstance () {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can answer these questions for yourself by reading the JLS.  (Opinions are not relevant.  You need facts.  For facts, read the specification.)

Comment: It is called `LazyHolder` because it is initialized lazily ... the first time that `getInstance()` is actually called.  Static variables of an inner class are initialized when the (inner) class is initialized.  The rules governing when a class is initialized are set out in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1

Comment: This is the [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom). It relies on when classes are loaded and initialized.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.